# mongoengine +django how to count the number of items of same content

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I want to count all the numbers of different values in a field.there is no "annotate()" to use in mongoengine ,then how could i count the number and order them by numbers

The only way i  thought out to solve this is use"distinct()"to find out the different values and then use "count()"to count each of the values
it's a stupid way to realize the result i want

Do you have any other ways ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoEngine has some map reduce helpers that should meet your needs.  The Queryset method `item_frequencies`[1] will meet your needs.  There isnt any special support for the new aggregation framework but support could be added in the future.

Example usage:

```
BlogPost.objects.item_frequencies('tags')
```

[1] http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html?highlight=item_frequencies#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.item_frequencies

Comment: @Ross I  find that we can only count all the frequency in a specific field,but what if I need to count the items in recent a few days or the nearest 10000 pieces of all the records?  Do you have any idea?

Comment: item_frequencies is a map reduce job under the covers - so you can always drop to pymongo and create your own map reduce or aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

MongoEngine itself has no special means to achieve this, but the MongoDB 2.2 aggregation framework lets you count documents, grouped by a field. I suggest using PyMongo's aggregate method directly with an aggregation pipeline to do this query:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html