# Django: How to get count of ValuesQuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-mongodb-engine

I am trying to get `count` to work on a `ValuesQuerySet`. According to Django documentation

```
values = Model.objects.values()
```

will return a `ValuesQuerySet` which is a subclass of `QuerySet`

```
Returns a ValuesQuerySet — a QuerySet subclass that returns dictionaries when used as an 
iterable, rather than model-instance objects
```

This would mean that all methods of `QuerySet` should work on `ValuesQuerySet` also.

However, when I try to do it I get an exception

```
values = Model.objects.values()
```

and then somewhere in my code

```
v_size = size_calc(values)

def size_calc(objects)
    return objects.count()

File "/home/talha/ws/events.py", line 
246, in size_calc
return objects.count()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 336, in count
return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 401, in    
get_count
number = obj.get_aggregation(using=using)[None]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 367, in  
get_aggregation
result = query.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(SINGLE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 213, in 
get_compiler
return connection.ops.compiler(self.compiler)(self, connection, using)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 582, in 
compiler
return getattr(self._cache, compiler_name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SQLAggregateCompiler'
```

`count` works seamlessly on normal `QuerySets`.. Could this be an issue with the backend drivers?

**Update**: I cannot use `len` after evaluating the `Queryset` as the data is huge and needs to be sliced before evaluation.

I am using Django with a mongodb backend. Related packages are

```
django==1.3.0
django-mongodb-engine==0.4.0
djangotoolbox==0.9.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could get past this issue without making changes in the `mongodb-engine` was to get the count using the normal `queryset`. So to get the count I used

```
count = Model.objects.all().count()
```

and for the data I that wanted, I used

```
values = Model.objects.values('a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try `len(values)`. That works fine

Comment: Thats not acceptable. `len` will evaluate the queryset. I do not want to do that as the data is huge. I need to slice the queryset before evaluating it. Have updated the question to give the clarification

Comment: @auny: The problem must be with mongodb. This works fine in mysql

Comment: Any idea where it could be? Mongo-db engine or djangotoolbox..Just wondering

Comment: May be since the error says `no attribute 'SQLAggregateCompiler'`, I wonder if the count() function is supported by mongodb

Comment: Yes it is. As I mentioned earlier, `count` is working on the normal querysets.

Comment: @auny So it is. Try for some other function to count the length. I am sure there are other alternatives

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42345/discussion-between-auny-and-aswin-murugesh)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
query_list = list(query_set)
len = query_list.indexof(query_list[-1])
```

This method is nothing similar to `len` function of list. As you might know `len` uses loop to calculate the length but above method exploits hashing.

Comment: Calling `list` on the `queryset` will evaluate it which is not what I want. The hash trick is too late and occurs after the heavy loading has been done

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue caused because of mongodb aggregation functions.**
*you can use* `Model.objects.item_frequencies('field')
*or [you can read here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468687/mongoengine-django-how-to-count-the-number-of-items-of-same-content)*

Comment: I see that under the covers it is map-reduce. I cannot afford to launch map-r jobs for running counts only..